# Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have this simple instruction

```
Stream.concat(manager.getChild().stream(), 
            manager1.getChild().stream())
            .map(dev -> dev.getSalary())
            .reduce(0, Integer::max);
```

that concats two List and return the developer that earning more. This returns the maximum salary of the objects in the stream, but how can I retrieve the object that has the maximum salary?

Comment: Why are you using `reduce` here?

Comment: What do you mean by "all the object"?

Comment: Remove the `map` and `reduce` and use `max` instead with an appropriate `Comparator` that compares by salary.

Comment: I try to use this `Employee rich = Stream.concat(manager.getChild().stream(), 
    manager1.getChild().stream())
    .max((dev1, dev2) -> Integer.max(dev1.getSalary(), dev2.getSalary())).get();` but not work very well.

Comment: Please, next time, choose a more fitting question title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Stream.max(Comparator<? super T> comparator)` method:

```
Stream.concat(manager.getChild().stream(),
    manager1.getChild().stream())
    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(dev -> dev.getSalary())
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't reach back to a previous step to get the stream element that provided the maximum salary; you have to compare the elements by an attribute.

To find the subordinate with the highest salary:

```
Employee max = Stream.of(manager, manager1)
  .map(Employee::getChild)
  .flatMap(Collection::stream)
  .max(Comparators.comparing(Employee::getSalary))
  .orElse(null);
```

I have assumed a class of `Employee` so method references can be used, and also refactored the code to a IMHO more usable/standard approach of starting by streaming the managers.

Comment: `flatMap` is overkill here

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov but it's more flexible: You can plug this flow on to any stream of managers, eg a `List<Employee>` via `.stream()`, or an `Employee[]` via `Arrays.stream()` etc. Conversely, hardcoding the stream calls is not scaleable or flexible and breaks `DRY`